# Retrofit: multiple query parameters in @GET

Tags: java, android, get, retrofit2

I have problem with multiple parameters in @GET. If I have two, everything is working fine, but if I have three (i need three) it skipping onResponse method and onFailure is executed. Does anyone know why?

This is interface

```
@GET("CalendarJson")
Call<List<Raspored>> getKalendar(
        @Query("department") String department,
        @Query("semester") String semester,
        @Query("year") int year);

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(basicUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();


KalendarService kalendarService = retrofit.create(KalendarService.class);
```

And this is where I call it

```
KalendarService.kalendarService.getKalendar(department,semester,year).enqueue(new Callback<List<Raspored>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Raspored>> call, Response<List<Raspored>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                raspored = response.body();
                //TODO
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Raspored>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the failure you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the datatype of your third parameter

Comment: but if I remove second parametar everything is working. Third parameter is `int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);`

Comment: No, i dont think i need it. I have url from which i need to get json data, based on that three parameters in url

Comment: How do you know it returns the correct json data? With the three parameters, json could be parsed as a list of 'Raspored' but not so with two parameters.